# Express js session cookie expires (maxAge)

Tags: node.js, express

How can I do something (e.g. query mysql) when a cookie expires and the session is deleted from Redis store? How can I catch that moment?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Node/Express: Session Expire Event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8539482/node-express-session-expire-event)

Comment: So, as I understood, I can't catch?

Comment: Thanks. If somebody know exactly, please tell.